# How can I sort different parts of a UNION MySQL query by different criteria?

Tags: mysql

I use a UNION query to bring in results from different tables when people are searching on my site.  People, Venues, and Events.

I'd like to sort People alphabetically, Venues alphabetically, and Events **reverse** alphabetically, since they start with a year and I'd like the most recent events to be at the top.

This is what I have currently (greatly simplified, but you get the idea).  It works perfectly, other than my desire to sort Events in reverse.

Can I achieve my end goal with this UNION query somehow, or do I need to break it out into multiple separate queries?  I have no problem doing that if needed, but since the code works well as it is, I'd prefer to make a small simple change to the below query, if anyone can think of a clever trick.

```
SELECT name AS name
     , name AS order
     , 1    AS grp

FROM PEOPLE

UNION

SELECT venue AS name
     , venue AS order
     , 2     AS grp

FROM VENUES

UNION

SELECT event AS name
     , event AS order
     , 3     AS grp

FROM EVENTS

ORDER BY grp ASC, order ASC
```

For instance if I could change `event AS order` to `STRING_SUBTRACT('ZZZZZZ', event) AS order`, or similar.  Is there any such function I could use?

Answer (score 1):

UNION will just append one table after the other. Write three simple queries and use union between them. In your case apply three different order by conditions, one for each query as you wish like in the example before.

```
(SELECT name AS name
     , name AS order
     , 1    AS grp
FROM PEOPLE
ORDER BY name asc)

UNION

(SELECT venue AS name
     , venue AS order
     , 2     AS grp
FROM VENUES
ORDER BY venue ASC)

UNION

(SELECT event AS name
     , event AS order
     , 3     AS grp

FROM EVENTS
ORDER BY event DESC)
```

Different story if  you want to order the unified results mixing them between the tables

Comment: You need parenthesis around each query (`(SELECT ... ORDER BY) UNION (SELECT ... ORDER BY)`).

Comment: Well I feel stupid now, I always thought you couldn't put order clauses on the component parts of a union query!

Comment: Hmmm, not working at the moment.  I don't seem to get any sensible order at all, they're certainly not alphabetical or reversed at the moment.  My fault for putting up too-simplified a version of my SQL maybe.  I'll see if I can figure it out, if you're certain that UNION can work like this.

Comment: consider that you have to wrap each select in brackets as per my edit

Comment: Yep, I'd done that. I've just tried a very basic example in Navicat and that doesn't work either.  Maybe this is an oddity of MariaDB which I neglected to mention I was using, but I would have thought it'd behave exactly as MySQL in this regard.

Comment: "However, use of ORDER BY for individual SELECT statements implies nothing about the order in which the rows appear in the final result because UNION by default produces an unordered set of rows"

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html

"If ORDER BY appears without LIMIT in a SELECT, it is optimized away because it will have no effect anyway."

Comment: then you need to go with an hack like this `SELECT pass1.* FROM 
 (SELECT TOP 1000 tblA.ID, tblA.CustomerName 
  FROM TABLE_A AS tblA ORDER BY 2) AS pass1
UNION ALL 
SELECT pass2.* FROM 
  (SELECT TOP 1000 tblB.ID, tblB.CustomerName 
   FROM TABLE_B AS tblB ORDER BY 2) AS pass2` where 1000 is a number as big as you need to catch all the results from each subquery. Or you can do it in the presentation layer

Comment: So was your answer fundamentally flawed, given the MySQL.com page I linked to?  Or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer I've come up with so far:

```
SELECT name AS name
     , name AS orderByAsc
     , ''   AS orderByDesc
     , 1    AS grp

FROM PEOPLE

UNION

SELECT venue AS name
     , venue AS orderByAsc
     , ''    AS orderByDesc
     , 2     AS grp

FROM VENUES

UNION

SELECT event AS name
     , ''    AS orderByAsc
     , event AS orderByDesc
     , 3     AS grp

FROM EVENTS

ORDER BY grp ASC
       , orderByDesc DESC
       , orderByAsc ASC
```

Works perfectly.